# How can I add local image in react native? I'm getting error while trying it

Tags: react-native

```
<Image source={require('./images/login.png')} style={{
                    width: 200,
                    height: 240,
                    flex: 1
                }} />
```

Screens
-Login.js
-images
     -login.PNG

```
None of these files exist:
  * login.png
  * Screens\images\login.png\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

[image: folder structure]
[image: code]

Comment: try to keep images folder outside your view components. So make a different folder in your root named assets. Then add image there. 

SO ```source={require('../assets/login.png')}```

Comment: still same error

Comment: show me your folder structure with respect to where you have placed image

Comment: try with login.PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a file with `login.png` extension but your local file is `login.PNG`

Change your local file to `login.png` and it should works.